# How would I conditionally format a cell based on conditions being true in the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I choose to edit the problem instead of having it spread out in the comments section.

"List of Invaders" - The names here, I want to be automatically crossed out when certain conditions are met. These conditions are: When all of the corresponding "invader" names are marked as "complete" with a "1" instead of the "0" in the corresponding "Completed" and "Crafted" columns. The light blue columns are where the names are "hidden" for the formulas to get info from.

So far, the marked answer was working for the initial intention, the problem arose when I wanted to add more columns for the array and or formula to look at.
I added a text box to the spreadsheet to explain what it is that should happen.

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1Nbt8Ct8pem0AqHwjvroX96hHDkrXwqPUZqngGEdFE/edit?usp=sharing

You are free to edit this one for testing. It is just a copy.
Thanks for all the help so far! And I apologize if I am causing confusion as to what I want, I hope this new example helps clear it up.

[image: Image of the test sheet.]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(G3:3, JOIN("|", QUERY(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY($E4:F, "select E where E is not null order by F"), 
 QUERY($E4:F, "where E is not null order by F"), {1,2}, 0), "select Col1 where Col2=1")))))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(G3:3, JOIN("|", QUERY($E4:F, "select E where F=1")))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without an array formula would be

```
=AND(COUNTIF($E:$E,"="&G3)=SUMIF($E:$E,"="&G3,$F:$F),SUMIF($E:$E,"="&G$3,$F:$F)>0)
```

and apply it to the range G3:V3 which is all of your invaders listed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This also worked. As in it crosses out the invaders based on if they corresponding names in column E has a 1 in column F next to it.

Is this expandable to include more columns to check for the invader names?
Look at my test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1614q49XwFTk8tB6i5QwNYRy7j3rDX9mewcXrSwnTOyY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes that can be done, Would column G have material names or quantities?

Comment: Hello.

I decided to make some changes to it all, as it seemed to get too "cluttered" for the fomulas to figure stuff out. Unless it is possible to make this cleaner, then this is what I got currently. I just need the invader list to be crossed out when they are no longer needed for anything, i.e I have crafted all items using the invader.
You can edit this as you please.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1Nbt8Ct8pem0AqHwjvroX96hHDkrXwqPUZqngGEdFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It was not possible?